# Jquery or some other conflict - quick help in determing

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I just need a quick help to determine what causes errors. So if it's not too much troubles, could someone take a look and point me in the right direction?

I have a wordpress site, and there is a problem with native galleries. They are not showing up. Gallery shows up for the fraction of second, then it just dissapires. 
It's probably a conflict, but don't know what exactly. Gallery is shown in html of the page, css then?

Please take a look http://tinyurl.com/ng7stxy

Thanks

Comment: can you show setting for gall.

Comment: is the same working in sidebar or bottom places ?

Comment: hello. what do you mean? native galleries settings aren't touched. there is a gallery post type in portfolio custom post type of the theme - but I just want to use native simple galleries.

Comment: i am getting css error

Comment: I've tried to put gallery shortcode in widget - no showing

Comment: @nanhe - what kind of error? can you paste it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome the properties of #gallery-1 are:

```
element.style {
display: block;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
height: 0px;
}
```

Something is setting the height:0px.

Comment: Thanks a lot - everything fixed!